# Is there a neater syntax for displaying a variable in erb?

Tags: ruby, syntax, erb

I'm new to Ruby, and I found the `<%= @my_variable %>` a little lengthy and less readable. Shouldn't erb have something like `${@my_variable}` (like the good old Velocity engine in Java)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

erb, as its name suggests, is intended for embedded ruby code. I don't think it has any other syntax beyond the following recognised tags:

```
<% Ruby code -- inline with output %>
<%= Ruby expression -- replace with result %>
<%# comment -- ignored -- useful in testing %>
% a line of Ruby code -- treated as <% line %> (optional -- see ERB.new)
%% replaced with % if first thing on a line and % processing is used
<%% or %%> -- replace with <% or %> respectively
```

If you don't like erb syntax there are other alternative template engines for Ruby. Take a look at [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/), [Liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/), [Mustache](http://github.com/defunkt/mustache) or [Tenjin](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/tenjin/).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is no according to the [ERB documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ERB.html).

> ERB recognizes certain tags in the provided template and converts them based on the rules  below:
>
> <% Ruby code -- inline with output %>
> **<%= Ruby expression -- replace with result %>**
> <%# comment -- ignored -- useful in testing %>
> % a line of Ruby code -- treated as <% line %> (optional -- see ERB.new)
> %% replaced with % if first thing on a line and % processing is used
> <%% or %%> -- replace with <% or %> respectively
> **All other text is passed through ERB filtering unchanged**.